# Flexible Regression Specification for Panel Data in Stata

Tags: regression, panel-data, stata

I am currently looking to estimate a somewhat complex regression model to analyze the market value of banks. The model can be found in Calomiris and Nissim ([2007](https://www.nber.org/papers/w12918.pdf)), and is pictured below.
The model is built with three different parts: activities of banks for which fair values are reported (FV variables) which are entered into the model with a coefficient set equal to 1, variables for which tangible data is available and whose value is calculated as the amount invested into an activity (w, i.e. w(loans)) multiplied by a proxy for the value created per dollar invested, and variables which primarily involve intangible assets, for which the earnings are used as a proxy for the value created.

My main problem is to enter the model with its brackets and its variables without coefficients into a Stata regression model.

Are you aware of a command with which that is possible? And if not in Stata, do you know another program in which this is possible?

Best,
Carl
[image: Calomiris & Nissim Model (as on page 55 of the linked paper)]
Free parameters are alpha, beta, delta, gamma, rho, lambda as well as v(Ltd), v(otherasset) and v(otherliab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have plenty of interaction variables here. For example $w_{loans}$ is interacted with $Yield_{loans}, Allow$ and so on.

In Stata this can be estimated via

```
reg mtb w_loans c.w_loans#c.yield_loans c.w_loans#c.allow
```

and so on. One `#` includes only the interaction term. Two `##` will include the interaction term as well as both variables in levels. I added `c.` because I assume these variables are continuous. If they are categorical, remove the `c.`. Then, `c.w_loans#allow#` will interact $w_{loans}$ with a dummy for every outcome of $Allow$ (and declaring one as the baseline).